# How to log "select2" selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I use "Select2" as dropdown list.
Now i´d like my page content to change upon my choice in Select2.

I´m stepping forward and have come to this:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// display logs
function log(text) {
  $('#logs').append(text + '<br>');
}
//SELECT2
$( ".select2_choose_objnr" ).select2({
    placeholder: "Välj Objekt..",
    ajax: {
        url: "php.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
  }).on("change", function(e) {
      log("change val=" + e.val);
    });
});
```

From this Js, i got: val=undefined
How can i change my code to get the selected value/text ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For v4.0.3

In the `change` callback, call `$(this).val()` to retrieve an array of selected values

```
.on("change", function(e) {
    log("change val=" + $(this).val());
});
```

`val()` is a function, not a property and you want to call it on `$(this)`

Comment: Thank you. My Js skills is not the best. But i´m learning thank to guys like you!

Comment: In my situation I had to write the normal `console.log(...)` instead of `log(...)` like in this answer. I think it is a typo, or I am missing something?

Comment: @RobinBastiaan you're missing that the OP had a method called `log` which appended values to the UI using HTML

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks, you are very right now looking back at the question!

Answer (score 3):

You can accesss the full data

```
.on('change', function(e) {
    // Access to full data
    console.log($(this).select2('data'));
});
```